# How to write a subscripted hyphen within matplotlib math text without TeX?

Tags: python, matplotlib, math-mode

TeX compiles `$A_{\textrm{C-C}}$` displaying a hyphen in the subscript. How can I produce the same result in matplotlib without using TeX? The command `\textrm` is from the amstext package and produces an unknown symbol error in the default math text.

I tried the following code (resulting in an unknown symbol error):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.axis([0, 2, 0, 2])
ax.text(1, 1, r'$A_{\textrm{C-C}}$')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inserting a Unicode hyphen (`u"\u2010"`) produced the correct text:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.axis([0, 2, 0, 2])

ax.text(
    0.1, 1.2, r'$A_\mathrm{C' + u"\u002D" + r'C}$' + 
    ' unicode hyphen-minus U+002D')
ax.text(
    0.1, 1.0, r'$A_\mathrm{C-C}$' + 
    ' ASCII hyphen')
ax.text(
    0.1, 0.8, r'$A_\mathrm{C' + u"\u2010" + r'C}$' +
    ' unicode hyphen U+2010 produces a result similar to textrm')
plt.show()
```

[Plot produced by the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yav2u.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.axis([0, 2, 0, 2])
ax.text(1, 1, r'$A_{C-C}$')
plt.show()
```

Hope it helps
from [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/mathtext.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, the answer is wrong. It produces a minus sign, which has a different meaning than `\textrm{C-C}`.

Answer (score 0):

As of [matplotlib version 3.8.0](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_3.8.0.html#mathtext-now-supports-text) you can simply use `\text` for upright text inside math text (or use `\mathrm` if you want a minus sign instead of a hyphen):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3, 2))
ax.text(0.4, 0.6, r'$A_\text{C-C}$', fontsize='xx-large')
ax.text(0.4, 0.4, r'$A_\mathrm{C-C}$', fontsize='xx-large')
```

[image]